# Из str в dict без повторений

Tags: python, словари

```
def find_phone_numbers(text: str) -> dict:
    result = re.findall(r'[\+\(]?[1-9][0-9 .\-\(\)]{8,}[0-9]', text)
    return result


print(find_phone_numbers("+372 56887364  +37256887364  +33359835647  56887364 +11 1234567 +327 1 11111111"))
```

Код выдает

```
['+372 56887364', '+37256887364', '+33359835647  56887364', '+11 1234567', '+327 1 11111111']
```

только надо оформить его в словарь, чтобы код страны был key, номер value и key не повторялся. Нужно получить

```
{'+372': ['56887364', '56887364'], '+333': ['59835647'], '': ['56887364', '1234567', '11111111']}
```

Телефонным номерам может предшествовать код страны, но это не всегда так. В этом упражнении код страны состоит из плюса + и трех цифр. Например, +372. Между кодом и номером телефона может быть пустое место, но не обязательно. Сам телефонный номер состоит из семи или восьми последовательных цифр. Что касается возвращенного словаря, ключи — это коды стран, а их значения — список строк телефонных номеров для соответствующего кода страны. Если номер не имеет кода страны, его ключ в словаре должен быть пустой строкой "". Для поиска телефонных номеров и их кодов стран необходимо использовать регулярное выражение.

Comment: совсем не понятно как `+327 1 11111111` превращается в `'':['11111111']` коды и длины телефонов могут отличаться в разных странах не обязательно код 3 значный а номер 7 значный

Comment: код выписывает ['+372 56887364', '+37256887364', '+33359835647  56887364', '+11 1234567', '+327 1 11111111']
но надо чтобы он делал из этого словарь

Comment: цель сгруппировать по кодам? сейчас в массиве `'+33359835647  56887364'` - это явно не то что нужно, мне так кажется, и я думаю если телефоны летят с фронта, то лучше там позаботится об общем формате

Comment: да, должно получиться так {'+372': ['56887364', '56887364'], '+333': ['59835647'], '': ['56887364', '1234567', '11111111']}
тоесть 372 это одна группа, 333, другая группа и так далее

Comment: ну так судя по вопросу именно это и получается

Comment: Изменила вопрос, дополнила его

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд регулярка была не очень точно составлена, моя тоже не идеальна, но работает лучше. По хорошему нужна тестовая группа номеров, для проверки корректности. Мы создаем 2 группы прямо в регулярке с помощью круглых скобок (выбираем код и номер), после формируем словарь, обрезая пробелы вокруг:

```
import re
def find_phone_numbers(text: str) -> dict:
    parse = re.findall(r'([+(]?[1-9]{2,3}[- ]?)?([0-9]{7,8})', text)
    dictionary = {}
    for code, num  in parse:
        code_trimmed = code.strip()
        num_trimmed = num.strip()
        if (code_trimmed in dictionary): # проверяем наличие кода
          dictionary[code_trimmed].append(num_trimmed) # cледующие номера
        else: 
          dictionary[code_trimmed] = [num_trimmed] # первый номер
    return dictionary

print(find_phone_numbers("+372 56887364  +37256887364  +33359835647  56887364 +11 1234567 +327 1 11111111"))
''' 
  {'+372': ['56887364', '56887364'], 
   '+333': ['59835647'], 
   '': ['56887364', '11111111'], 
   '+11': ['1234567']}
'''
```

Обычно я не испытываю трудностей с составлением регулярок, так как понимаю их синтаксис, однако иногда могут пригодится онлайн инструменты для наглядной выборки (сайт https://regex101.com/):

[image: скриншот работы сайта]

В качестве последнего предложенного ответа была составлена регулярка:

```
r'(\+[1-9]{3,3}[- ]?)?([0-9]{7,8})'
```

опишу что она делает:

`(\+[1-9]{3,3}[- ]?)?`  - это группа для кода

- в ней говорится что сначала должен идти `+`
- затем ровно 3 числа (или {от 3-х, до 3-х}) цифр от 0 до 9
- после этого может идти либо один `пробел` либо одно `-`, но это не обязательно
- и сама эта группа кода тоже не обязательна
- за необязательность в обоих случаях отвечает `?` поэтому их 2 штуки

`([0-9]{7,8})` - это группа номера (тут все просто)

- в ней говорится что мы ищем последовательность длиной {от 7-ми, до 8-ми}, состоящую из цифр от 0 до 9

Comment: можете помочь исправить ошибку? AssertionError: assert {'': ['55327886'], '466': ['5567342']} == {'': ['5567342', '55327886']}

Comment: дайте тестовую строку

Comment: print(find_phone_numbers("+372 56887364  +37256887364  +33359835647  56887364 +11 1234567 +327 1 11111111"))

должно получиться     # {'+372': ['56887364', '56887364'], '+333': ['59835647'], '': ['56887364', '1234567', '11111111']}
Но код почемуто делит +11 на код страны тоже

Comment: для начала я хотел бы глянуть AssertionError дайте только строку номеров без python

Comment: `+11 1234567` не удивительно что `+11`  тут код

Comment: можно сделать ограничения кода до 3х цифр исправьте `2` ку в регулярке на `3` и получите

`{'+372': ['56887364', '56887364'], '+333': ['59835647'], '': ['56887364', '1234567', '11111111']}`

Comment: спасибо за помощь!

Comment: пожалуйста, изучайте регулярки, как видите вещь полезная)

Comment: нашла проблему, при вводе 466 5567342 код выдает 466': ['5567342'], а должен '': ['55327886']

Comment: это не проблема, просто регулярка этого не учитывала, попробуйте такую `r'(\+[1-9]{3,3}[- ]?)?([0-9]{7,8})'`

Comment: именно по этой причине я и говорил что нужно при себе иметь полный тестовый набор номеров чтобы составить регулярку правильно иначе это может затянуться на неопределенное время, так же Вам может пригодится сайт для тестов https://regex101.com/ - очень удобно

Comment: дополнил свой ответ описанием содержимого последней регулярки